# jQuery Cycle, Internet Explorer and Image Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mouseevent, cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle for this diagram, and I'm using an Image map for the controller.

http://nuoz.com/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#circle1').click(function($) { 
        jQuery('.rotate').cycle(0);
        jQuery('.rotate').cycle('pause');
        return false; 
    });
    jQuery('#circle1').mouseout(function($) { 
        jQuery('.rotate').cycle('resume');
        return false; 
    });
});
```

I tried both mouseout, and mouseleave. Esstentially the client wants the rotation to resume after the user rolls off of the pie piece. Could it be that IE doesn't recognize an image map area as an element? Again, works fine in Firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client ended up changing the functionality and it actually solved my original problem. I just removed the mouseout function and replaced it with a copy of the click function but switched the event to hover, and it worked great.